# Opening routes directly or reloading the page, downloading some file

Tags: nuxtjs3

I've deployed my Nuxt app to Vercel and connected by custom domain to it. After deployment, what I can see, if I open a route directly, the page is getting downloaded (try here - https://stackwealth.in/blogs/).
If I open my home route (https://stackwealth.in/), it will open correctly, but any other routing in my app is getting download on reload or direct accessing it.

On Local it was not happening.

Why is that happening?

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devServer: {
        port: 5100
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,
            apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
        },
        supabaseUrl: process.env.SUPABASE_URL,
        supabaseKey: process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
        ghostUrl: process.env.GHOST_URL,
        ghostKey: process.env.GHOST_API_KEY
    },
    devtools: {
        enabled: true,
        
        timeline: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    router: {
        options: {
            scrollBehaviorType: 'smooth'
        }
    },
    pages: true,
    components: [
        {
            path: '~/components',
            pathPrefix: false
        }
    ],
    app: {
        head: { ... }
            
    },
    plugins: [],
    css: [
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        '@/assets/scss/app.scss'
    ],
    modules: [
        '@stefanobartoletti/nuxt-social-share',
        '@bootstrap-vue-next/nuxt',
        'vue3-carousel-nuxt',
        'dayjs-nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/supabase',
        '@nuxt/content',
        '@nuxtjs/robots',
        'nuxt-gtag',
        'nuxt-simple-sitemap'
    ],
    gtag: {
        id: '...',
        config: {
            page_title: '...'
        }
    },
    supabase: {
        redirect: false
    },
    robots: {
        rules: {
            UserAgent: '*',
            Disallow: '',
            Sitemap: 'https://stackwealth.in/sitemap.xml'
        }
    },
    nitro: {
        prerender: {
            crawlLinks: true,
            routes: ['/', '/sitemap.xml']
        },
        compressPublicAssets: {
            gzip: true,
            brotli: true,
        },
    },
    sitemap: {
        sources: [
            '/api/__sitemap__/blogs',
            '/api/__sitemap__/faqs',
            '/api/__sitemap__/opportunities',
            '/api/__sitemap__/calculators',
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.

Looks like belpw code, was creating issue. Removed it now working fine

```
  compressPublicAssets: {
        gzip: true,
        brotli: true,
    },
```